# Padding not working on IE 8

Tags: bug, status-declined

I was looking at SO on IE 8 and realized it did not look like it did in Chrome.  Chrome you have padding just below the user until the divider to the next question.  I have provided an image of my IE browser.  It is not zoomed or anything.

[image: Screen Padding messed up]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE 8 is no longer supported.

We are currently supporting IE 9 and 10, and once IE 11 is out, we will drop IE 9 support.

See [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: Number one reason to work for SO.

Comment: @KatieK - What? Not needing to still account for IE6?

Comment: New browsers in = old browsers out. (OK - degraded support.) That's...  living the dream, man.

Comment: Heh. Guess someone doesn't like the fact that their browser is not supported...

Comment: Actually, I downvoted because I think the policy is bad. I use FireFox as my browser, so I'm fine personally, but Windows XP is still supported by Microsoft and prevents upgrades past IE8. So what you're essentially saying is that for people who are 'behind the times', but are still using perfectly valid software, you won't support their use case. Whilst I appreciate the cost-benefit of supporting older browsers as a developer, I think you've gone a step too far with version choices.

Comment: @staticbeast - The [Windows lifecycle fact sheet](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows/products/lifecycle) shows XP end of life on April 14, 2009 - over 4 years ago. The _special_, extended support is about 9 months away. Regardless - the line _has_ to be drawn somewhere. Note that we do try to support older browsers, but for something like this, that is cosmetic only, we will not expand resources.

Comment: I understand and sympathise, I just think the line should have been drawn the other side of IE8, whilst their are users who can't install a higher version without a complete OS upgrade. In nine months time, by all means drop support for it. -sidenote, I read a lot of Meta and my views on your support (Stack Exchange, not you personally) for 'unsupported' browsers was a draconian 'does not care'. I may have softened a little if it was more obvious you were being reasonable, I.e. if the last line of your comment was used instead of the first line of your answer...